# Why is Samba treating user as “others” instead of guest account or specified user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, samba

Samba 4.7.6 on Ubuntu Server 18.04. I want a samba share folder accessible by one specified user from Debian 9 and another accessible by guests with read and write permissions on both. (I am using Samba because I will occasionally access it from Windows in the future.) When I try to mount the share it asks for the password for root@//server/share and after entering it I get "permission denied." If I set "guest ok = yes" it mounts successfully, but my user is treated as "others" in the file permissions instead of the guest account "nobody." From the Linux client, if I save a text file in the share folder it is indeed owned by "nobody" with permissions 644. It is read-only to me unless I give "others" write access to the file on the server. I can't change the permissions from the Linux client because I don't own the file.

I followed the official Ubuntu Server documentation, their Samba wiki, and the Using Samba, 2nd Edition e-book, as well as several "tips and tricks" posted by people on the internet. Specifying valid users, forcing users, changing owners, changing permissions, adding users to smbpasswd, creating a user map file, making the names of the [share] sections different from the directories, are all unsuccessful. I don't have SELinux. I feel like I have tried everything.

Here is my [smb.conf](https://gist.github.com/JaguarDown/be1e38ba245a9d15ed890cdc6767860e)

Permissions on server:

`zachary@zserver3:/srv/samba$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 zachary zachary 4096 Sep  2 08:27 personal
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody  nogroup 4096 Sep  2 07:59 share`

Permissions on client:

`zachary@debian-thinkpad:/media/samba$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 zachary zachary 4096 Sep  2 08:27 personal
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 nobody  nogroup    0 Sep  2 07:59 share`

I expect to have guest read and write access to the public share with no password and read/write access to the private share as user zachary. However, I have no access whatsoever unless I set `guest ok = yes` but then I am not even given the guest account and instead treated as "others." Edit: From the Linux client, if I `cd` to the share folder in a terminal I cannot write to the directory or files. However, if I use sudo I can. For example `sudo touch test` creates a file called `test` owned by `nobody:nogroup` with `644` permissions. If I do `sudo vim test` and edit the file I can write to it. If I don't use `sudo` permission is denied. Why is it requiring `sudo` if the directory and files are owned by the guest user and group `nobody:nogroup`?

Here is the mount error:

`zachary@debian-thinkpad:~$ sudo mount //zserver3/private /media/samba/personal
[sudo] password for zachary: 
Password for root@//zserver3/private:  ************
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

EDIT#2: I set `log level = 2`. When I `tail -f /var/log/samba/log.` mounting the public share does use the guest account "nobody" but says `read=yes write=no`. Then, when I mount the private share the log says that the guest account is not permitted to access that share. So, it's trying to use the guest account instead of the user "zachary."

Here is the log when trying to mount `[private]`

`[2019/09/02 11:17:26.356241,  2] ../source3/smbd/service.c:338(create_connection_session_info)
  guest user (from session setup) not permitted to access this share (private)
[2019/09/02 11:17:26.356946,  1] ../source3/smbd/service.c:521(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`

EDIT#3: When I comment out `map to guest = Bad User` I get nothing in the log when mounting `[private]` so I guess it considers my credentials to be a bad user and is just dropping it. When I uncomment it again and attempt to mount the log again shows it is trying to use the guest account. P. S. still don't know why guest account doesn't have write access on public share.

Comment: What UIDs/GIDs do you see in `/proc/<pid>/status` of the corresponding 'smbd' connection-handler process on the server?

Comment: I'm an intermediate user so based on your question I did `ps aux |  grep smbd` then `ls /proc/<pid>/status` on the processes listed and those directories were empty. Please see "EDIT#2" on the original post for more info on logs.

Comment: According to this [this old samba how-to](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/old/Samba3-HOWTO/install.html#id2553078) I changed smb.config to [this](https://gist.github.com/JaguarDown/2613e11c56700efc0f18b454f26b2215) to just start simple and share the server admin user's home folder. `sudo mount //zserver3/homes /media/samba/personal` still didn't work so after some more digging I ran `sudo mount.cifs //zserver3/homes /media/samba/personal -o user=zachary,rw,credentials=/etc/samba/.zachary` and this succeeded. I could browse the share in the file explorer and had full r&w permissions.